# Which is the distance between the two points?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

A spiral is formed by infinitely joining half squares, wherein the side lengths of the squares are halved at each step. The side length of the first square is 5cm. 
The right endpoint of the spiral approaches infonotely a point E. 
Which is the distance between E and A?

We have also the picture:

[image]

Do we have to compute the limit of the spiral?

So, do we have to use the limit of $\frac{5}{2^n}$, which is $0$ ?

Comment: You don't take the limit you take the infinite sum.

Comment: Ahh, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5}{2^n}$ ? Or is this fraction wrong? @JustinStevenson

Comment: It's not very clear to me how the spiral is formed. Do you have a picture with  the squares?

Comment: Yep that looks good!

Comment: It is just the picture I posted above @JairTaylor

Comment: With that sum do we compute the point $E$ ? oR the length of the spiral? @JustinStevenson

Comment: I guess where the sum starts really depends on how the squares create the spiral, i'm assuming that the length from the left most point to the right most point is the side length of the initial square in which case your sum looks good.

Comment: Your computing the length to from A to E (without following the spiral).  If you have follow the spiral it is much harder.

Comment: So, the distance from $A$ to $E$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5}{2^n}=5$, right ? We have that the first square has length 5cm. But we use the halb so, $\frac{5}{2}$ then the next is $\frac{5}{2^2}$ and so on. Have I understood everything correctly? @JustinStevenson

Comment: Yep, that is correct!

Comment: Which is the total length of the spital? How could we compute that? @JustinStevenson

Comment: To compute that you would need to assume each arc forms a perfect semi circle and then you would set up a similar infinite sum using the formula for the perimeter of a circle.

Comment: Which is exactly the difference between the distance of A and E and the total length of the spiral? @JustinStevenson

Comment: The length of the spiral is exactly that, and the distance between A and E is just the the length of a straight line connecting the A and E.

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you!! :-) @JustinStevenson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, let's take the first square as one *unit*. Then, moving from A to the first axis crossing we move one unit, next crossing is -1/2 unit, next is +1/4 unit, and so on. Therefore, the distance from $A$ to $E$ will be

$$5 \text{ cm}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}=5\text{ cm}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=3.\dot3 \text{ cm}$$

This result agrees perfectly with a numerical solution.

Comment: Why do we take one the positive and once the negative symbol?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, at each half-turn of the spiral we are moving alternately further and closer to point A as move ultimately to point E.

Comment: How about some recognition for the correct answer? Do you have any questions about the answer?

Comment: I am still confused about the alternating series, about the minus sign. Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: I'll try. Looking at your diagram, let's say start at Point A and we want to find the distance to E. If we follow the first arc to the x-axis, we travel one *unit*, but, we have gone too far. So we follow the second arc to the x-axis; the distance from A to there is one unit minus one-half unit. And now we are not far enough. Next follow arc to the axis and we overshoot again, the distance from A is now 1-1/2+1/4 units. One the next arc we undershoot and the distance from A is 1-1/2+1/4-1/8 units.  (continues)

Comment: Continuation: The point is that we are bouncing back and forth (minus and plus the distance from A) as we zero in on point E. Does that help? Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Ahh... So, the way described in the comments of my question, to start from $\frac{5}{2}$ then take then half of that, $\frac{5}{2^2}$, and so on, is wrong, right?

Comment: Yes, that wrong because when every fraction is positive, you are *hopping* further and further away from point A.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: Happy to help out. Anytime!